# How to test my Material UI component function handlers?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I'm having troubles testing my component function handlers.

I have this component:

```
class MUIToolbar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: this.props.title,
    anchorEl: null,
    value: 0,
    open: false
  };

  handleMenu = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  homeRedirect = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/groups');
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl, value, title } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.root}>
          <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow} onClick={this.homeRedirect}>
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Tabs
              value={value}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              classes={{ root: classes.tabsRoot, indicator: classes.tabsIndicator }}>
              <Tab
                classes={{ root: classes.tabRoot, selected: classes.tabSelected }}
                label="Groups"
                component={Link} to="/groups"/>
            </Tabs>
            <div>
              <IconButton
                aria-owns={open ? 'menu-appbar' : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                onClick={this.handleMenu}
                color="inherit">
                <AccountCircle />
              </IconButton>
              <Menu
                id="menu-appbar"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                anchorOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                  vertical: 'top',
                  horizontal: 'right',
                }}
                open={open}
                onClose={this.handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Log out</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/groups" component={Groups} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const enhance = compose(
  defaultProps({
    title: 'Daily Track',
  }),
  withStyles(styles),
  withRouter,
);

export default enhance(MUIToolbar);
```

So, I want to test `handleMenu`, `handleClose`, `handleChange` and `homeRedirect` and I'm doing it like this way:

```
describe('Testing Toolbar component', () => {
  let mount;
  let shallow;
  let mountWrapper;
  let shallowWrapper;
  let props = {};
  beforeEach(() => {
    props.onClick = jest.fn();
    mount = createMount();
    shallow = createShallow();
    mountWrapper = mount(<Router><MUIToolbar /></Router>);
    shallowWrapper = shallow(<MUIToolbar />);
  });

it('should simulate user IconButton click.', () => {
    const instance = mountWrapper.instance();
    const userIconButton = shallow(<IconButton />);
    userIconButton.simulate('click');
    jest.spyOn(instance, 'handleMenu');
    expect(instance.handleMenu).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

And I got this error

```
Cannot spy the handleMenu property because it is not a function; undefined given instead
```

I tried many ways to do that but I couldn't.

Thanks for the help